# Colocar a Thumbnail do Wordpress como background

Tags: wordpress, background, thumbnail

Preciso colocar a thumbnail do Wordpress como background em uma div

Atualmente está com img mesmo, usando o Loop::thumbnail()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode inserir inserir a url da thumbail em um style dentro da div, deste modo toda vez que você alterar a thumbnail ela será alterada no background da div tambem:

```
<div style="background-image: url("<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()) ?>");">
</div>
```

Lembre-se de passar o id do post como parâmetro da função **get_the_post_thumbnail_url()**.

Comment: Deu certo! Tinha feito algo semelhante aqui também. Valeu!